# Estimate number of digits of 333!

Tags: combinatorics, approximation, estimation

How do I estimate the number of digits of 333! in a rigorous way?

What I did so far is just counting in the following manner: 
1 digit for the first 99 numbers and then 2 digits for the remaining 234 numbers of 333!. This sums up to approx. 567 digits. Which is very rough compared to 698 digits which is the real solution.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "mathematically"? Is there another, non-mathematical way to do it? Like "philosophically"?

Comment: [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: $99$ is closer to adding two digits than it is to adding one digit when you multiply by it.

Comment: @Klangen, I am referring to a more rigorous and accurate way instead of a simple hand counting method. I edited the question. Thanks for the remark–

Comment: Throwing `log(333!)/log(10)` into WolframAlpha suggests the estimate of $698$ digits. Very rough upper and lower bounds suggests somewhere between $323$ and $1332$ digits; how precise would you like the estimate to be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stirling's approximation $$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ is spooky accurate.  Take the (base-10) log of both sides, and you get
$$\log n!\approx \frac{1}{2}(\log(2\pi)+\log n)+n(\log n-\log e)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-n\log e+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log n$$
$$\approx 0.4-.43n+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log n$$

Plugging $n=333$ into it, I get $698.45+$

Comment: Is the error may affect the result?

Comment: Once you take logarithms, the $\sim$ technically changes into something else. Not that $\sim$ is _wrong_, but it has a formal meaning in this case, and using it after taking logarithms undersells the accuracy of Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @Arthur thanks.  I forget that $\sim$ has a technical definition.

Comment: The approximation (and any errors I made along the way) affect the answer a little.  According to W|A, $\log(333!)=697.014+$

Comment: Additionally, my problem was that I didn't remember how to calculate the digits of any number $n$ given an arbitrary base $b$: $1+\lfloor log_b (n) \rfloor$. In our case we have  $1+\lfloor log_{10} (333!) \rfloor$. Applying Stirling's formula yields $1+\lfloor 697.0142 \rfloor = 698$. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3):

For any (large) $N$ we have

$$\log(N!)=\sum_{k=1}^N\log k={1\over\ln10}\sum_{k=1}^N\ln k={1\over\ln10}\sum_{k=1}^N(\ln(k/N)+\ln N)={N\over\ln 10}\left(\ln N+{1\over N}\sum_{k=1}^N\ln(k/N)\right)\approx{N\over\ln10}\left(\ln N+\int_0^1\ln x\,dx\right)={N\over\ln10}(\ln N-1)$$

For $N=333$, this gives

$$\log(333!)\approx695.35$$

which suggests there are approximately $\lceil695.35\rceil=696$ digits in $333!$.

To be more rigorous about the integral approximation, we have

$$-1=\int_0^1\ln x\,dx\lt{1\over N}\sum_{k=1}^N\ln(k/N)\lt\int_{1/N}^1\ln x\,dx={\ln N+1\over N}-1$$

so

$${N\over\ln10}(\ln N-1)\lt\log(N!)\lt{N\over\ln10}(\ln N-1)+{\ln N+1\over\ln10}$$

which gives the following range for the number of digits:

$$696\le\lceil\log(333!)\rceil\le699$$

Comment: $\log N!=\log 2+\log 3+\sum_{k=4}^N\log k > \log 2+\log 3+\int_3^N\ln x\,\mathrm dx$ gives $\log(333!)>696.003$, so your $696$ can be improved to $697$. Unfortunately, $333!$ is just 3% above a power of $10$, hence to ultimately decide between the last two possibilities, we need quite some improvement on the lower estimate.

Comment: @BarryCipra, I think there should be a "$+$" instead a "$-$" in the numerator of the estimation of the upper bound: $$[...]\lt\int_{1/N}^1\ln x\,dx={\ln N +1\over N}-1$$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Philipp, yes, thank you. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

What we want is the (integer part of) the value of
$$
\log_{10}1 + \log_{10}2 + \cdots + \log_{10}333 + 1
$$
You found an approximation by assuming that every number in this sum below $\log_{10}100 = 2$ was equal to $1$, and every number $2$ or higher was equal to $2$. This will, as you have found, underestimate the true answer.

I think it would be one step better to round each of the numbers in the sum above to its closest integer instead, rather than rounding most of them down. Since $\sqrt{10} \approx 3.16$, that means that $\log_{10}3$ gets rounded down to $0$, everything from $\log_{10}4$ to $\log_{10}31$ gets rounded to $1$, everything from $\log_{10}32$ to $\log_{10}316$ gets rounded to $2$, and the remaining few get rounded to $3$. This gives a final answer of
$$
3\cdot 0 + 28\cdot 1 + 285\cdot 2 + 17\cdot 3  + 1= 650
$$
which is a lot closer to the true answer (48 away rather than 131 away).